# How to select by DATE and add default sequenct while insert in select command?

Tags: sql, db2

copy a new row with SPECIALITY = 305 in same table where

```
PROV_TYPE      =014          
SEQ_NO         --------> start by 1,2,3 like that  
SPECIALTY      =300                                                               
D_PROC_PT_SP_BEGIN current date                             
D_PROC_PT_SP_END   noo end date!! blank
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough, could you please elaborate as to what needs to be done?

Comment: i have to add a new row with SPECIALITY = 305 in same table where
    PROV_TYPE      =014          
    SEQ_NO         --------> should start by 1,2,3 like that  
    SPECIALTY      =300                                                               
    D_PROC_PT_SP_BEGIN current date                             
    D_PROC_PT_SP_END   noo end date!! or more than current date

Comment: I think you are being over-simplistic showing us what you are trying to do. I would really like to have a better idea of what the source data you are trying to copy are like and what the corresponding output for *those data* should be.

Comment: oh okay.i have a table with columns ....
provider type ...
sequence number ..
speciality ..
begin date..
end date ...
now i need to add more rows having column "speciality = 305  table by just copying the current rows having provider type = 1,2,3,4 and speciality = 300
the only problem is the column 'sequence number'
i need to auto increment it for each provider type record ..
For example .. i need to:
have sequence 1 for provider type 1 and specialty 300
1 for provider type 1 and specialty 300.......
2 for provider type 1 and specialty 300.........

Comment: then for another provider type .. sequence counter shall start from 1 again ..
i hope i explained well thios time

1 for provider type 2 and specialty 300...

Comment: AUTO INCREMENT FOR INDIVIDUAL PROVIDER TYPE IS THE PROB

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't pay attention that you are new here. I meant you could edit *your original post* to clarify all those things. Sorry again. There's the `edit` link just under the post.

Comment: This is still not clear.  I suggest that you write out an `INSERT` statement that does as much of this problem as you know how to do, and post that in your question along with an explanation of what else needs to be done.